# How to route traffic from a Express app route with parameters to an EC2 instance?

Tags: express, amazon-ec2

I have an Express app running on an EC2 instance and configured with a domain name. One of my routes has parameters, like `/name/:id`. Based on `:id`, I want to redirect to different EC2 instances. All I can find are examples of routing from subdomains, not Express routes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http-proxy with express for achieving this.

example,

```
var PROXY = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = PROXY.createProxyServer();

app.get("/name/:id", function(req, res){ 
  const targetHost = 'http://ec2-1-your-vm:80'; //default host
  if(req.params.id === 2) {
    targetHost = 'http://ec2-2-your-vm:80';
  }
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: targetHost });
});
```

This is the dependency link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!